# tmux server being killed when shell closes

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, tmux

Tmux server and my tmux sessions are being killed at the end of my SSH sessions.

SSH session:

```
# timepoint 0

$ tmux
# timepoint 1

# ^D
[detached (from session 0)]
# timepoint 2

$ tmux a
# timepoint 3
# ^D
[detached (from session 0)]
# timepoint 4

$ exit
# timepoint 5
```

Output of `ps` command as seen from a second SSH session:

```
# timepoint 0
$ sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tmux

# timepoint 1
$ sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tmux
khouli   29401  0.0  0.0  19492  2884 pts/6    S+   02:31   0:00 tmux
khouli   29403  0.0  0.0  21792  3112 ?        Ss   02:31   0:00 tmux

# timepoint 2
$ sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tmux
khouli   29403  0.0  0.0  21792  3112 ?        Ss   02:31   0:00 tmux

# timepoint 3
$ sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tmux
khouli   29403  0.0  0.0  21792  3112 ?        Ss   02:31   0:00 tmux
khouli   29752  0.0  0.0  19492  1140 pts/6    S+   02:31   0:00 tmux a

# timepoint 4
$ sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tmux
khouli   29403  0.0  0.0  21792  3112 ?        Ss   02:31   0:00 tmux

# timepoint 5
$ sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep tmux
```

At timepoint 0, there are no tmux processes. At timepoint 1, a tmux client and server are running as expected. After detaching from the server at timepoint 2 there is only the server running. Re-attaching works as expected and at timepoint 3 there is both a server and client running. At timepoint 5 we see that when the SSH session closed it took down the tmux server with it which defeats the whole point of using tmux.

What's going on or how can I debug this?

tmux is version 2.0. The shell is bash.

This is without a `.tmux.conf` file. I have a `.bash_logout` but it only contains comments.

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused by using `AllowUsers` in my sshd config file. Either not using this option or including `root` in `AllowUsers` fixes this -- tmux sessions started over ssh persist after the ssh session is closed.

Having `PermitRootLogin no` in my sshd config appears to prevent an actual remote `root` login even with `root` in `AllowUsers`.

The whole thing feels very quirky since without `root` in `AllowUsers` I can still ssh in and then `su` to become root.